# Weblogic memory leak on deploy undeploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, weblogic

Weblogic 10.3.5 running with 32 bit JRockit R 28.2.4-14 using `-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m` always gets out of native memory after 5-8 Undeploy-Redeploy cycles of our Java EE EAR files.

According to the error message and what is displayed in VisualVM, it is not the Java Heap that gets too full but insufficient system memory which is available.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: class allocation, 865324184 loaded, 464M footprint,
in check_alloc (src/jvm/model/classload/classalloc.c:215).

Attempting to allocate 1G bytes

There is insufficient native memory for the Java
Runtime Environment to continue.

Possible reasons:
  The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
  In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
Possible solutions:
  Reduce memory load on the system
  Increase physical memory or swap space
  Check if swap backing store is full
  Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
  Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
  Decrease number of Java threads
  Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
  Disable compressed references (-XXcompressedRefs=false)

        at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:381)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:377)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:313)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1322)
```

I understand the possible solutions that are suggested, but as everything is fine if the application is only deployed once, it seems classes are not correctly freed when undeploying. A heap dump after undeployment shows there are many of our classes left in memory. Shouldn't they be garbage collected then?

The path to GC Root shows a Thread `<JNI Local> java.lang.Thread @ 0x129ac778 JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket Native Stack, Thread`. There is no traffic on the server and I don't know why this stays to be active.

Answer (score 2):

This memory leak is most likely caused in the perm-gen space (this is how it's called on Hotspot JVM). JRockit doesnt have dedicated Perm-Gen space, but uses "regular" heap space for this. 
Have a look at the following sites which I found really helpful for understanding what's happening here:

[What is a PermGen leak](http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak)

[Busting PermGen Myths](http://plumbr.eu/blog/busting-permgen-myths)

Comment: Right that's the error I get when using Hotspot JVM. Even after increasing MaxPermGen to 256M (of 1024!) I keep getting the error. I'll check the links you provided...

Comment: According to the links you gave, any long running threads or database connections might still have references. I suspended a batch client accessing the server via t3, but that's not the problem. After Undeployment, I still have some of my objects alive, and looking at the references I see that `<JNI Local> java.lang.Thread @ 0x129ac778  JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket Native Stack, Thread` is displayed as the culprit. What is that thread and why is it still active?

Comment: That looks like a debug connection. Do the memory leaks also happen when you don't attach a debugger?

Comment: Yes, they also happen without debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) very helpful for debugging PermGen leaks:

My approach is usually something like this:

- Do a heap dump after undeployment
- Find one of you application classes (doesn't really matter which, all should leak). Alternatively display duplicate classes.
- Display the path to the GC root

Why the fix looks like depends on the cause.

Comment: That's what I did. See last paragraph of the question. Doesn't really help me in this case what this thread still is and why it references my classes.

Comment: Have you found the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some classes are holding to the classloader which causes the full application to leak on redeploy. You can read about [this article about classloaders](http://zeroturnaround.com/labs/reloading-objects-classes-classloaders/).